# Function is not running. No error in the console log

Tags: javascript, forms, function, validation

I'm trying to execute this function and well I can't get it to run. My console.logs are not running in the console at all. This function should validate emails on submit only for specific domain.

```js
function emailValid() {
  console.log('first')

  var formInput = document.querySelectorAll('t186__input');
  console.log('input');
  var formSubmit = document.querySelectorAll('t-submit');
  console.log('submit');
  formSubmit.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('click');

    if (formInput.val().indexOf('@rbc.com') !== -1) {
      return true;
      console.log('hey2');
    } else {
      alert("You have entered an invalid email address");
      return false;
    }

  });

}
```

```html
<div class="t186__wrapper">
  <div class="t186__blockinput">
    <input type="text" name="EMAIL" class="t186__input t-input js-tilda-rule" value="" placeholder="Your E-mail" data-tilda-rule="email" style="color:#000000; border:1px solid #000000;" />
  </div>
  <div class="t186__blockbutton">
    <button type="submit" class="t-submit" style="color:#ffffff;background-color:#000000;">Subscribe</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, you have a number of errors. Corrected.

1/.

1. Do not need `querySelectorAll`
2. You wrapped your init code in a function, so never called.
3. Your querySelector was not using a `.` class modifier.

```js
var formInput = document.querySelector('.t186__input');
console.log('input');
var formSubmit = document.querySelector('.t-submit');
console.log('submit');

formSubmit.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

  console.log('click');
  if (formInput.value.indexOf('@rbc.com') !== -1) {
    return true;
    console.log('hey2');
  } else {  
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("You have entered an invalid email address");
    return false;
  }


});
```

```html
<div class="t186__wrapper">
  <div class="t186__blockinput">
    <input type="text" name="EMAIL" class="t186__input t-input js-tilda-rule " value="" placeholder="Your E-mail" data-tilda-rule="email" style="color:#000000; border:1px solid #000000; "> </div>
  <div class="t186__blockbutton">
    <button type="submit" class="t-submit" style="color:#ffffff;background-color:#000000;">Subscribe</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

A further tidy

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target.matches('.t-submit')) {
    let regEx = /@rbc.com/;
    if (regEx.test(document.querySelector('.t186__input').value) === false) {   
      e.preventDefault(); 
      e.stopPropagation();
      alert("You have entered an invalid email address");
      return false;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="t186__wrapper">
  <div class="t186__blockinput">
    <input type="text" name="EMAIL" class="t186__input t-input js-tilda-rule " value="" placeholder="Your E-mail" data-tilda-rule="email" style="color:#000000; border:1px solid #000000; "> </div>
  <div class="t186__blockbutton">
    <button type="submit" class="t-submit" style="color:#ffffff;background-color:#000000;">Subscribe</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Wrapped in a from and deal with submit event. Have to assume there must be a form element in there somewhere :)

```js
// In this example we need to wait for the DOM to be ready. 
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  // Code in here will execute the the HTML is loaded and the DOM is ready for use.
  setUpFormListener('t_frmSubmit'); // <--- replace with your form class name
});

function setUpFormListener(frmClassName) {
  // In this demo, we bind directly to the form submit. (note we use form.[class] to ensure we only select the form
  document.querySelector(`form.${frmClassName}`)
    .addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
      let regEx = /@rbc.com/;
      if (regEx.test(document.querySelector('.t186__input').value) === false) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        alert("You have entered an invalid email address");
        return false;
      }
    });
}
```

```html
<form class="t_frmSubmit" submit="_blank"> 

  <div class="t186__wrapper">
    <div class="t186__blockinput">
      <input type="text" name="EMAIL" class="t186__input t-input js-tilda-rule " value="" placeholder="Your E-mail" data-tilda-rule="email" style="color:#000000; border:1px solid #000000; "> </div>
    <div class="t186__blockbutton">
      <button type="submit" class="t-submit" style="color:#ffffff;background-color:#000000;">Subscribe</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</form>
```

Comment: Hey Bibberty, thank you for your fix. It works well but the submit button is still sending the info even though the preventDefault() function and return false are there. How can I make is stop sending the form?

Comment: We need to change to a submit event, will look and fix later. I will add a sample 'form' element to the example.

Comment: Thank you! Just for the record I need to use this specific html.

Comment: Understood, but I assume you have this inside a '<form>' element?

Comment: @IgorVoytt can you check, I assume you are wrapping the inputs in a `<form>` element. If you can look and maybe post the element, we can add code to fix.

Comment: @IgorVoytt I have update with a section that has code for form. Example is working, you will need to adjust CSS selector etc.

Answer (score 0):

`querySelectorAll('t186__input')` and `querySelectorAll('t-submit')` looks for elements with tags `<t186__input` and `<t-submit`.

Based on your `HTML` these are classes on the elements. So use a `class` selector

`querySelectorAll('.t186__input')` and `querySelectorAll('.t-submit')`

Also `querySelectorAll` returns an array of nodes, so you will have to iterate over them first to access each element.

If you expect only a single element with that class use `querySelector` instead.

Also you have just defined the function but not calling the `emailvalid` function anywhere.

Comment: I think there is a fundamental misunderstanding in the code. The events are being added to the form inside the validate method. The call out on the selectors is a correct, but I think there is an overall issue. Also, note the use of `val()` this is jQuery syntax and not valid in Vanilla along with cancelling the event, we only want to cancel if the email is invalid.